# How to retrieve data from mongodb using C# drivers version 2.2.0 and VS2015

Tags: c#, mongodb, visual-studio-2015

I have a simple mogodb database and I want to display the content of a document using C#. So far I have written the following code:

```
var mongo_client = new MongoClient();
var mongo_database = mongo_client.GetDatabase("database_name");
var collection=mongo_database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("collection_name");
    using (var cursor = await collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToCursorAsync())
    {
        while (await cursor.MoveNextAsync())
        {
             foreach (var doc in cursor.Current)
             {
                 Console.WriteLine(doc);
             }
         }
     }
```

The above code has been inserted into an async method. The connection is established but it looks like it can't run the code inside using. I've added to the project the following references: MongoDB.Driver, MongoDB.Driver.Core and MongoDB.Bson.
The instruction `Console.Writeline(doc);` doesn't display anything because it is not executed. But why?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your filter:

```
var mongo_client = new MongoClient();
            var mongo_database = mongo_client.GetDatabase("database_name");
            var collection=mongo_database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("collection_name");
            using (var cursor = await collection.Find(FilterDefinition<BsonDocument>.Empty).ToCursorAsync())
            {
                while (await cursor.MoveNextAsync())
                {
                    foreach (var doc in cursor.Current)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(doc);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Also, if you can fit all records in memory (is it a small collection?) you can try simply `ToListAsync`:

```
var mongo_client = new MongoClient();
            var mongo_database = mongo_client.GetDatabase("database_name");
            var collection=mongo_database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("collection_name");
            var allRecords = await collection.Find(FilterDefinition<BsonDocument>.Empty).ToListAsync();

           foreach (var doc in allRecords)
           {
               Console.WriteLine(doc);
           }
```

Comment: Are there documents in your 'document_name' collection?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. This is the correct code:

```
            var mongo_client = new MongoClient();
            var mongo_database = mongo_client.GetDatabase("database_name");
            var collection=mongo_database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("collection_name");
            var records = collection.Find(FilterDefinition<BsonDocument>.Empty).ToList();
            foreach (var doc in records)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(doc);
            }
```

You don't need to create any async methods. You don't need to use the await operator. It's much easier.

Comment: It also works if you replace "FilterDefinition<BsonDocument>.Empty" with "new BsonDocument()".

Comment: Just because you don't 'need to use it' doesn't mean you shouldn't use it